# Change a php variable for entire document

Tags: php, variables

I want to change the effects of a set variable that is at the beginning of a document for example:

```
if(isset($var)){
 // Show Loading Message
}
 // Whole bunch of code to load a report
unset($var); // To remove the loading message
```

I want the deceleration at the end of the code to remove the loading message that is above by removing the variable. Is there any way to do this with PHP?

Thanks!

**Note:** I understand how the program would usually work, the question is if there is a way around this typical model output being definite, using PHP.

Comment: Are you using php to generate html?

Comment: Yes I am using php to pull data from a MYSQL Database and stick it into a table.

Comment: This sounds like you seriously misunderstood something about program flow... when it output something, it was output. You can't go back in time and prevent yourself from outputting it ;)

Comment: I know that is usually the case so I am wondering if there is a way I can change it.

Comment: You'll need to approach it from the browser angle - either a page reload or an ajax check

Comment: Assuming you're generating an HTML document, you could set some javascrip at the bottom of the page to delete the loading message - but odds are your user would never see the message, unless you're generating a "huge" page.

Comment: Well, you obviously can't travel in time. What you *could* do is adding and removing a loading message at the client side (i.e. using Javascript) as you have to document available there and can manipulate it - but then you have to issue the request for the report via Javascript (specifically, via AJAX).

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to show a message saying something like "Loading your report" to the user, then build the report, and after remove the "Loading" message and display the report. This is similar to like flight search sites, when you search for a flight you get a message saying "searching through flights" and after a few seconds you are shown your results. The only way to do this is really to use an intermediate page that kicks off the report generation and after a few seconds you check if it is done. when done you redirect to a page with the report.

Comment: Thank you! I will just have to use Javascript I guess, it would be sweet if PHP had some kind of floating variables that could change at anytime during the document without having to reload and post them, so I guess it doesn't exist, even though I was hoping it could to save some time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to remove something that has already been outputted to the browser using PHP - once you output the loading message, from PHP's perspective it is gone and out the door.

You'd have to have some javascript on the page to manipulate the DOM and remove the text node that way.

For example:

```
print '<div id="loading_message">Loading, please wait</div>';

... bunch of code ...

print '<script type="text/javascript">var e = document.getElementById("loading_message"); e.parentNode.removeChild(e); </script>';
```

Comment: We Chrises must stick together.  The Steves and Johns of the world are a suspicious lot whom we must never trust.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it client side; all HTML generated by a PHP script is sent to the browser and can't be retrieved again. To do it client side, give the loading div an ID of, say, `#loading`. Then, at the end of the PHP script, stick some JavaScript in that will hide the div. Here's a jQuery example:

Loading div:

```
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

jQuery (echo this from the bottom of your PHP file):

```
<script>
$("#loading").hide();
</script>
```

**EDIT**

For a vanilla JavaScript solution, please see @Chris's answer

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: thanks James, jQuery is way cleaner, I am just too lazy to attach the jQuery file so I am going to leave it messy haha Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ha ha I know exactly how you feel when it comes to laziness XD. Glad I can be of at least a little help :-P

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are actually ways to process PHP and send to the browser window BEFORE things are done processing.

It's a hokie, hokie, hokie way of doing things but I wanted to at least share.

You can use the `flush()` command at any point to output the current moment in processing out to the browser while the page is still rendering.

You can also do your processing and store the output of the processing in the output buffer before it goes out.

```
ob_start();

//Do a bunch of PHP stuff

$results = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $results
```

Like I said...HOKIE for general web page processing.  Use jQuery or your own JS, but maybe this will some in handy somewhere else.